# How can I dynamically call the variable from other python file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, variables

I have an a.py file, which stores multiple list inside.

```
total_list = 2

a0 = ['example_string','example_string2']
a1 = ['example_string4','example_string3']
```

and I have a b.py which will read the list fron a.py. I want to do something like this which is able to loop to get each of the lists in a.py.

```
import a

for i in range(a.total_list):

 steps = "\n".join(a.a+str(i))
 print(steps)
```

and I get this error

```
AttributeError: module 'a' has no attribute 'a'
```

I had tried the globa() and local() methods but it is not working.

Comment: you might consider making `total_list` a list of list variables: [https://onlinegdb.com/oyIBRiMDl](https://onlinegdb.com/oyIBRiMDl).